# Get PSObject array size or count

Tags: powershell, psobject

I create an array like this:

```
$Array = @()

$Item = New-Object PSObject
$Item | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name item1 -Value test
$Item | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name item2 -Value test

$Array += $Item
```

Now I want to add a check to determine if `$Item` is empty before adding it in `$Array`. How can I get the member count of `$Item` ?

I tried stuff like :

```
$Item.count
$Item.length
@($Item).count
($Item | Measure).count
($Item | Get-Member).count
$Item.psobject.members.count
```

But none of them gives me the actual member count.

Comment: For future "dupe close" folk: This does looks a lot like [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103213/how-do-i-get-the-length-of-a-pscustom-object/53103518), at least by title, but I'd say that one is more specifically about iteration and this one is clearly & nicely to the length/count point. I was going to edit that question's title to mention iteration, but thought that would be too heavy-handed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the hidden `.PsObject.Properties` to either check for

`$Item.PSobject.Properties.Value.count` or
`$Item.PSobject.Properties.Names.count`

```
$Item = New-Object PSObject
$Item.Psobject.Properties.value.count
0

$Item | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name item1 -Value test
$Item.Psobject.Properties.value.count
1

$Item | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name item2 -Value test
$Item.Psobject.Properties.value.count
2
```

Comment: Indeed (+1); it's strange that the collection returned fro  `.properties` has no `.Count` or `.Length` property; a more concise alternative is `@($Item.psobject.properties).Count`

Comment: Oddly, this did not work for the result of an `Import-CSV` statement, which generates a `PSCustomObject`.  I could not find any built-in `Count` or `Length`.  I had to use this code:  `$Obj.PSObject.Properties | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Count"`

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is:

```
($Item|Get-Member -Type NoteProperty).count
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `Get_ItemCount` function could help:

```
Function Get_ItemCount {
    $aux = $($item | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty)
    if ( $aux -eq $null ) {
        0
    } elseif ( $aux -is [PSCustomObject] ) {
        1
    } else {
        $aux.Count
    }
}

$Item = New-Object PSObject
Get_ItemCount                  # 0
$Item | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name item1 -Value test
Get_ItemCount                  # 1
$Item | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name item2 -Value test
Get_ItemCount                  # 2
```

**Output**

```
PS D:\PShell> .\SO\55064810.ps1
0
1
2
PS D:\PShell>
```